# Is it possible to get user input with micro python?

Tags: micropython

How do I get user input with micro python? Whenever I try using

```
input()
```

I get an error saying it is not a valid command. How do i fix this?

Comment: Which port are you using ( / which device are you using MicroPython on)? It appears that `input()` is implemented in some ports (pyboard, unix) but potentially not all.

Answer (score 1):

Use sys.stdin.readline()

```
import sys

print("What is the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything?")
answer = sys.stdin.readline()
if answer == "42\n":
    print("correct!")
else:
    print("incorrect!");
```